# Stack upload just hangs

Tags: haskell-stack

I'm trying to upload my package to Hackage. After it prompts me for a password, it seems to hang. Eventually (after ~3 minutes) I hit Ctrl-c to stop it.

```
$ stack upload .
Getting file list for /home/amy/néal/grid/
Building sdist tarball for /home/amy/néal/grid/
Checking package 'grid' for common mistakes
Hackage username: AmyDeBuitleir
Hackage password: 
^CSave hackage credentials to file at /home/amy/.stack/upload/credentials.json [y/n]?
```

I also tried `stack upload . --no-signature`, with the same result. Eventually I uploaded using the upload link on the Hackage website. But why didn't the stack upload command work?